# Check network connection from an IP address with Python

Tags: python, network-programming, ip-address, python-sockets

How can I check if there is still connection from a specific ip address using python.

Comment: I belive you mean *to* a specific IP address. that is, a [ping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python)?

Comment: Yes Elazar,to a specific address and yes it's a ping. If I ping this ip address and if there is connection,it will return true, if not, it will return false.

Comment: Then look at the link in my comment. The answer is there.

Answer (score 4):

ping the ip address

```
import os
#192.168.1.10 is the ip address
ret = os.system("ping -o -c 3 -W 3000 192.168.1.10")
if ret != 0:
    print "pc still alive"
```

well in any case you really want to check for availability of incoming connection on the PC you are trying to connect you need to make a program that will receive the connection which is already out of the question.

Comment: Based on the question as it currently stands, I believe the OP wishes to check the status of an incoming connection, not whether an IP is accessible.

Comment: I tried this but it displays "pc is still alive" even though there is no connection.

Comment: use `ping -n 3 -w 3000 192.168.1.10`

Comment: shouldn't it be ret == 0 when pc still alive?

Comment: ret will be always 1 in Windows. It works only in Linux.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understood the OP is looking for active connection **FROM** certain ip, meaning he wants to check locally if there is active connection exists. It looks like something along lines of netstat to me. There are several options:

1. You can use [psutils](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) as demonstrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993731/how-do-i-access-netstat-data-in-python) post. You will want to cycle the active processes and query active connections.
2. You could use [netstat.py](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/python/psutil/examples/netstat.py) - a clone of netstat by Jay Loden, Giampaolo Rodola' to do the job for you.

**Added**:

You can do something like that:

```
import psutil

def remote_ips():
    '''
    Returns the list of IPs for current active connections

    '''

    remote_ips = []

    for process in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            connections = process.get_connections(kind='inet')
        except psutil.AccessDenied or psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            pass
        else:
            for connection in connections:
                if connection.remote_address and connection.remote_address[0] not in remote_ips:
                    remote_ips.append(connection.remote_address[0])

    return remote_ips

def remote_ip_present(ip):
    return ip in remote_ips()
```

This is how it works:

```
>>>remote_ips()
['192.168.1.50', '192.168.1.15', '192.168.1.52', '198.252.206.16', '198.252.206.17'] 
>>>remote_ip_present('192.168.1.52')
True
>>>remote_ip_present('10.1.1.1')
False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [socket library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html):

```
import socket

try:
    socket.gethostbyaddr(your_ip_adrress)
except socket.herror:
    print u"Unknown host"
```

Comment: Hi kadi, I tried this but is says Unknown Host None even thought there is a connection.

Comment: Hi Nethan, If Host is not reachable it means that there is no connection opened on this address.

Comment: @kadi `gethostbyaddr` doesn't say anything about connectivity (in any sense). It merely returns the name associated with the IP address. It's perfectly valid for a name to be returned for a host which is not currently up. Or for no name to be returned for a host that *is* up.

Answer (score 1):

if you are on Windows:

```
import os
ret = os.system("ping -n 3 1.1.1.1")
if ret != 0:
     print("Ip address responding")
```

The -n argument is for how many times to ping it

if you are on LInux:

```
import os
ret = os.system("ping -c 3 1.1.1.1")
if ret != 0:
     print("Ip address responding")
```

Comment: I think that (at least the one for windows) doesn't work if you are connected to it via VPN...