# Python: Get data from netstat

Tags: python, perl, netstat

Is there any module or easy way to access `netstat` data using Python script in Linux? I remember that in Perl you could just execute `system("netstat -parameters")` and save output into array, which isn't cleanest and finest way in my opinion. I wounder if there are any modules in Python which can make it possible to access same data as can be accessed using `netstat -ltupn`? If "socket" then how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You could start a subprocess and either wait for the results with communicate.

Example:

`command = Popen(['command'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
result1,err= command.communicate()`

or follow one of the suggestions given in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993731/how-do-i-access-netstat-data-in-python)

Comment: Okay, so with that said, there is no module which can help me to avoid executing commands and saving output?